# By default all the series are collapsed in gantt chart but I want to hold up them

Tags: highcharts

By default all the series are collapsed in gantt chart but I want to hold up them at first.
How to ask gantt chart to hold up the series, when it gets loaded?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know methods for collapsing/expanding are not yet available but it will be exposed in the future https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/highcharts-gantt-alpha/

Comment: Cant we manage them with the external JS for now?

Comment: I believe you can modify the gantt chart internal code and expose methods responsible for collapsing. Source for the gantt is here https://github.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.src.js

Comment: Thanks Morganfree. I got the solution :)